# How to change ImageView source programatically several times?

Tags: android, imageview

Once the image is pressed, it changes and plays a sound. After the sound is played I would expect to return to the previous image (same ImageView), which isn't happening.

xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_red_off"
    android:src="@drawable/red_orig"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="160dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
/>
```

java code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
.
.
.

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (colorRed > threshold)) {
            whatColor = "Red";
            imageRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        }
   .
   .
   .
   }

playSound(whatColor);
imageRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_orig);
.
.
.
}
```

in playsound method:

```
if ((color != "None")) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, animal);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        };
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: play a sound with the help of thread or background services.

Comment: @smb6 What are you using to play the sound? SoundPool?

Comment: @MikeIsrael, I'm using Mediaplayer

Comment: Use handler to add delay.

Comment: @smb6 so I would say that the answer that Herry submitted could be a solution for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some thing like this .

Let's say image which has img1 set once user touch you change it's img now when MediaPlayer complete playing you can use `setOnCompletionListener` Once play complete use imageview object to change image rather then doing it in OnTouch of image .

Like below :

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, animal);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
          if(img.getTag().equal("second")){
             //Then set first image here 
           }
        };
    });
```

Comment: This solution works. But I'm not sure I understand why, could you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: At moment when your imageView show it have some image apply by from your xml file and now as you said in ur question that you want to change image only when user touch it and once file play complete then only you want to change back to previous one .So in your touch you are playing sound so it simple to have change image back once that play sound completed so i advise you to use `setOnCompletionListener`.Hope thing now clear to you.